# Connect raspberry pi3 to Ubuntu via SSH command ~ Permission denied

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, ubuntu

i have been struggling for over 2 weeks to connect my Raspberry PI 3 to Ubuntu , i tried a bench of solutions that i found online (Via Putty or VNC viewer ... ) finally i think that i make it happend with SSH via Ethernet cable RJ45. Now the issue is when i try to connect to the Pi via `ssh @10.0.2.15` (IPV4 adress) it takes me to  pi@10.0.2.15 's password i type the regular password "raspberry" and unfortunately it didn't work the error message is permission denied.try again.

Thank you for your time.

Any suggestion could be helpful for me Please :)

Comment: are you trying to SSH to or from the Pi?

Comment: Hello , the issue was that I didn't get the right raspberry's ip address. so what  I did I plugged the raspberry card on my TV with an HDMI cable (If you get a no signal error ; just add this line to the config.txt file by adding this line `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`(Very common issue)) also with an Ethernet cable to my router then with `sudo ifconfig` you should able to get what you need to connect your raspberry card to your laptop. I'm using vnc server because its the easiest way to get the raspberry's desktop.